# Upvoting comments shifts the text

Tags: bug, comments, design, up-votes

If you upvote the first comment on a post, if it has a score of 0, then the text shifts:

> [image: animation demonstrating the problem]

Comment: I can't say it as a bug. It is the normal behaviour I think but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call this a bug. The same thing happens if you're the person who brings the score to double or triple digits, and it'd be wasteful to always reserve the necessary space for 3 digits.